# What do the USCF crosstable result letters mean?

Tags: tournament, notation, uscf

In the crosstable for a tournament I played, I didn't play a round and it was listed as `H`. What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result codes are defined in the [USCF website FAQ, under Member Services Area](https://new.uschess.org/frequently-asked-questions-faqs#MembershipServicesAreaMSA).

> **What do all the result codes in a crosstable mean?**
>
> Here's a list of the result codes currently in use:
>
> ```
> W  A win for this player
> L  A loss for this player
> D  A draw for this player
> U  This player was not paired in this round
> B  A full point bye
> H  A half-point bye
> F  A forfeit loss
> X  A forfeit win
> Z  A forfeit draw
> ```
>
> Special Use Codes
>
> ```
> N  A win for this player (but not a loss for the other player)
> S  A loss for this player (but not a win for the other player)
> R  A draw for this player (but not a draw for the other player)
> I  Game In Progess (will be used for correspondence events only)
> ```
>
> Note: The N, S and R codes are used by TDs for unusual circumstances, resulting in the players being assigned results for ratings purposes that are not consistent with each other, such as a win for one player and a draw for the other player.