# How does a forfeit draw come about?

Tags: tournament, uscf

In the [answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/44965/224) to the question ["What do the USCF crosstable result letters mean?"](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/44964/what-do-the-uscf-crosstable-result-letters-mean), there is reference to a "forfeit draw". This term seems self-contradictory and nonsensical. The referenced USCF page provides no explanation for how it would happen. The only explanation I can come up with for such a result is if both players fail to appear for a game they are supposed to play against one another, but it seems that should be a double forfeit loss (0-0 score) instead of a draw (1/2-1/2 score). Unfortunately, searching has not found an explanation. Is this idea correct, or is it something else (and if so, what)? Or is this just one way it could happen?

Comment: Since I happened upon his question, maybe it's a draw by "time forfeit"? https://www.chesscincinnati.com/wp-content/uploads/Comparison-of-FIDE-and-USCF-Rules-2021.pdf